# XC1020: Build error occurred in the XAML MSBuild task in WWF4.0 console application

Tags: .net, xaml, msbuild, compiler-errors, workflow-foundation-4

I have started with doing a sample in Widows Workflow Foundation 4.0, i have created a console application with a sequential workflow and tried to execute it, but then I am getting the error as "could not load file or assembly, microsoftcsharp.dll or some other dependencies are missing".

I have checked out the references and i could see that this dll is added, unable to get the root cause of the error.

would be helpful if i would get any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Fusion Log Viewer. That will show you any assembly bind failures.

Comment: hi, have opened he fusion log viewr, but iam unable to see any logs, and log view button is in disabled mode.

Comment: You need to elevate the viewer by running it as an administrator. The the buttons will be enabled.